# How to get substring of a SearchKit result column?

Tags: civievent, searchkit

How to get substring of a SearchKit result column? I want to truncate the event start time from `17:15:00` to just `17:15`.

**What I have:**

- My test setup is newest WP 6.3.2 and newest CiviCRM 5.66.0.
- CiviEvent: several events, with a starting date and time, e.g. `17:15`.
- SearchKit: a search that gives me open events in the next 2 weeks.
  The result presents no actions, no sorting, just a static table listing.
- Form Builder: a form to hold the results from the search.
- WordPress: a page that contains the shortcode with my search.

**What I want:**

- The final output contains a column with *event start time including seconds*. It is silly to show an event start time with seconds - and I understand that this comes from the timestamp format in the database.
- I do not see any suitable field transformation that I could apply in the SearchKit.
- In the reports output part of SearchKit, each column has the `Rewrite Text` function using "SMARTY conditions" but it is not clear to me how that works. My latest attempt is `[{TIME_start_date|substr:0:5}]` but that generates no output. **Can you give an example?**
- I cannot think of another way to truncate the time value, or any way to do any kind of substring operation at all.

How can I get rid of the seconds in the time column?

[image: event listing]

[image: field transformations]

(ignore the missing localisation of the weekday and month words)

Comment: I think SearchKit is sorely missing a "Format Date" column setting. Do you think you could sponsor that feature?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by the word "sponsor", @Coleman? I sadly cannot provide funding, and my PHP skills are not up to snuff ... but I might be able to contribute in other ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with Coleman that it would be great to have Format Date in SearchDisplays.

If you want to do this in the Smarty rewrite, you can do something like `{"[start_date]"|date_format:"%H:%M"}`, without the field transformation.

Comment: I made a small adjustment to match the actual field name: `{"[TIME_start_date]"|date_format:"%H:%M"}`  and that worked like a charm! <3 Thank you Lars! I can see this code is syntactically a little different from my previous, failed attempts. I was close though :-) Gotta learn more about how Smarty is written inside SearchKit now.